# How to use toolseparator inside a repeater in qml?

Tags: qt, qml

Toolseparator is not working inside repeater. I need to show the image and text under that one line after each content, so to show the line i have used tool separator but it's not working, it just override all the content by showing only lines. Here is the example

```
Repeater {
  model: 10
  Row {
    leftPadding: 10
    spacing: 10
    Rectangle {
      height: 100
      width: 200
    }
    Text {
      text: "Username"
    }
    ToolSeparator {
      height: 25
      width: 335
      orientation: Qt.Horizontal
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide a minimal, complete example that runs without errors (i.e. either use a http URL for your image or replace it with a Rectangle) and is properly formatted?

Comment: you can replace image with a rectangle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've done few mistakes, my friend.

- If you are going to use [`Repeater`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-repeater.html) -- *typically* you should use it inside of some of the positioning components (e.g. `Column`, `Row`). So in your case, `Repeater` should be inside `Row`. By the way, never neglect to review official Qt documentation: [Repeater Detailed Description](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-repeater.html#details); [Using QML Positioner and Repeater Items](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qml-positioners.html). In addition to this there is great learning source QmlBook, and for example its [Quick Starter](https://qmlbook.github.io/ch04-qmlstart/qmlstart.html?highlight=repeater).
- If you want to show your components one under another -- you should use [`Column`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-column.html) component, and not [`Row`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-row.html).

---

If I understand you correctly you are going to get something like this:

[image: Screenshot of application]

Use this code as a reference:

```
 Column {
    spacing: 10

    Repeater {
      model: 4

      Rectangle {
        id: background
        height: 50
        width: 200
        color: "bisque"

        Text {
          id: text
          color: "chocolate"
          text: "Username " + modelData
          anchors.centerIn: parent
        }

        Rectangle {
          id: separator
          anchors {
            bottom: parent.bottom
            left: parent.left
            right: parent.right
          }
          height: 5
          color: "goldenrod"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```